# how to get results from an event

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, nodejs, smart-contract-wallets

Let's say I have this smart contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2/access/Ownable.sol";



 contract AccessControl is  ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable  {
     event ReturnAccessResult( address indexed _from, uint256 id, string action, string mesg);
address owwner;
struct registration {
    uint id;
    bool isValued;
}

struct  list_nfts { 
    uint256 _id;
    address subject;
    address owwner;
    string  permission  ;// 3 choix " lecture , ecriture , lecture + ecriture "
    bool isValued;
   
}

mapping (uint256=> list_nfts) nfts ;
mapping (address=> list_nfts) subjectnft ;

 mapping(address => registration ) SubjectRegistration; // for registration check

 constructor()  ERC721("AccessControl", "MJT") {
        owwner = msg.sender  ;
 }

        //cree le jeton au mm temps stocker access
     function CreateNFT(uint256 tokenId , address _subject , string memory _permission ) public onlyOwner   {
        _safeMint(_subject, tokenId );
          //registration
          nfts[tokenId].subject= _subject;
          nfts[tokenId]._id= tokenId;
         nfts[tokenId].permission= _permission;
         nfts[tokenId].isValued= true; 
          nfts[tokenId].owwner= msg.sender; 
          subjectnft[_subject].isValued=true;
      
    } 
     

 // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId); }
  
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)  returns (string memory)
    {  return super.tokenURI(tokenId); }
   
   function accessControl(address _subject , string memory _action ) public returns (uint256 _res) {
   
  uint256 idn=1; 
  uint256 idn2;
  uint256 resultat=5;

  //require (SubjectRegistration[_subject].isValued == true, "yu are not registrated");
      
  
if (subjectnft[_subject].isValued=false){
   //si le nft n'existe pas 
   idn2=idn+1;
CreateNFT(idn2 ,_subject, _action );
resultat=1;
emit ReturnAccessResult(_subject, idn2, _action, "jeton cree avec succes");
}
else 
resultat=2;
_res= resultat;
emit ReturnAccessResult(_subject, idn2, _action, "jeton deja cree");
}}'
```

And in node js side I use this code to extract results from the event ReturnAccessResult. Ps

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
// Set the 1st account for transactions
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var subject= "0xdf75c43a312b21f2475f6576a6e95394c03f4759";
var previousTxHash = 0;
var currentTxHash = 0;
let tableau = [];

// Set the ABI
var yourContract = web3.eth.contract([]);
// Set the contrcat address
var myACC = yourContract.at('0xcACc9C78e87E30060a379A454759873d35f4f68A');
const readline = require('readline');
const { endianness } = require('os');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout
});
rl.setPrompt('  Send access request?(y/n)');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', (answer) => {
if('y' == answer) {

console.time('Execution Time');

currentTime = new Date().getTime()/1000;
currentTxHash=myACC.accessControl.sendTransaction("0x12588a54175d2c60c4b80f2b37a5865fdb99ab7e","ABB", "read",currentTime, {from:
web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:3000000});


myACC.ReturnAccessResult ({fromBlock: 'latest',toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, result) {

    if (!error) {
    console.log(result);
        console.log('\n');
console.timeEnd('Execution Time');  //avoid dupicate event capturedr
        console.log("Contract: "+result.address);
        console.log("Block Number: " + result.blockNumber);
         console.log("Tx Hash: " + result.transactionHash);
        console.log("Block Hash: "+ result.blockHash);
        console.log("Time: " + result.args.id);
        console.log("Error Message: " + result.args.mesg);

  }

});

}

else{
console.log("Ummmmm....");
rl.prompt();
process.exit(0);
}});
rl.on('close', function() {
console.log('Have a great day!');
process.exit(0);
});
```

The result is just pending not showing anything. I used to try this code for event (js) with other smart contract codes and it worked perfectly, but not this time. Is the problem in the contract code? Ps: I used other ways to call events but still not working.

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? The code looks like a very old version. In recent versions you could wait for the transaction to be mined, and then inspect the transaction's receipt.

Comment: Indeed, I had an old version of web3, I updated it. How can I inspect the transaction's receipt, please?

Comment: Just await on the function call `const txReceipt = myACC.methods.accessControl("0x12588a54175d2c60c4b80f2b37a5865fdb99ab7e","ABB", "read",currentTime).send({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:"3000000"})`.